# Error when I delcare my own variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, median

I was learning about calculating the median value in MySQL. I looked up this code solution to calculate the median value of lat_n variable.

```
set @ct := (select count(1) from station);
set @row_id := 0;

select avg(lat_n) as median
from (select * from station order by lat_n)
where (select @row_id := @row_id + 1)
between @ct/2.0 and @ct/2.0 + 1;
```

But I get an error:
" ERROR 1248 (42000) at line 4: Every derived table must have its own alias"

I know this error usually occurs when I have sub-query statements with no alias, which I see two in my code, but I have never implemented this with declared variables before.

And for the bonus question... how can I approach this problem as someone who is used to PostgreSQL and using CTEs?

This is my first time posting a question on S.O.!!!

Thanks for the help!

EDIT 1:
This question is from HackerRank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

I get it to work with no error by using this:

```
set @ct = (select count(1) from station);
set @row_id = 0;

select avg(ordered.lat_n) as median
from (select * from station order by lat_n) as ordered
where (select @row_id := @row_id + 1)
between @ct/2.0 and @ct/2.0 + 1;
```

But it now says I got the wrong answer (I calculated a value w/o an error but it is wrong) so I am confused if the code is good to go?

EDIT 2:
Per @ysth suggestion. The following code also works in getting rid of the error and provides the same value of `83.89` as does the code in EDIT 1. But apparently it is not the correct answer. I'm going to close this question but if anyone notices a problem in the syntax of the code to calculate a median value of a variable, then please let me know.

The code:

```
with ordered as(
    select lat_n, 
    row_number() over(order by lat_n) as row_id,
    (select count(1) from station) as ct
    from station
)

select avg(lat_n) as median
from ordered
where row_id between ct/2 and ct/2 +1
```

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: The error does not have anything to do with variables, you have a subquery without an alias in the from clause.

Comment: @ysth it says 8.0.20

Comment: @Shadow yeah I got it to work but apparently the calculation is wrong.

Comment: with version 8, you shouldn't use variables, you should use ROW_NUMBER() (and a join or CTE for the total count)